# How to write an htaccess rule for nginx to protect a directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to protect some type of files in the /uploads directory from non logged in users in a Wordpress website. The thing is that I am trying to translate the instruction for a Nginx server.

The htaccess syntax would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

I know it is not an "ironclad" solution, but it is enough for my need.
This is how it should look like:

```
# nginx configuration location ~ ^.*(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$ { }
```

1. But how should I write the cookie part?
2. Moreover how can I add a rule to redirect the user to a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just checking for the existence of a cookie isn't a secure way of protecting files - It's very easy for an attacker to add a cookie.

But, if you wan't to check the existence of a cookie, you can use:

```
location ~ ^.*(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$ {
    if ($cookie_CookieName = false) {
        return 301 http://example.com/redirect-here;
    }
}
```

The only other issue you have now is that the Wordpress logged in cookie name contains a random number - eg `wordpress_logged_in_12345`

So, you'll need to add another cookie to show that a user is logged in.

Comment: thanks @Chris , is it possible to write a wildcard cookie name? *wordpress_logged_in.*

Comment: I don't believe so, as the cookie name is a variable name, which has limited usage (Such as just checking if it exists). If they had a variable that listed the cookies, you would be able to a regex on it ... But I don't believe they do.